# How to make a global integer that works with substringFromIndex?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, macos, nsstring

Merry Christmas!!! I've ran into a little issue and I need help. I have NSString that is like so:

```
NSString *newStr = [someString substringFromIndex:(someNum)];
```

I'm trying to define (someNum) globally. I believe it needs a NSUInteger to work probably. The reason I need it defined globally is because I'm using some "if statements" to define someNum and someNum will return undeclared if not global. Is it possible to use a objectForKey with this NSString? I'm just stuck on what to do. I tried to define someNum with:

```
#define someNum 5
```

but I will have multiple instances of someNum and it won't work. Like so:

```
if (someName = @"abc"){
#define someNum 5
}
if (someName = @"abcd"){
#define someNum 6
}
NSString *newStr = [someString substringFromIndex:(someNum)];
```

I also tried:

```
if (someName = @"abc"){
NSUInteger someNum = 5;
}
if (someName = @"abcd"){
NSUInteger someNum = 6;
}
NSString *newStr = [someString substringFromIndex:(someNum)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statements are completely incorrect, you are performing pointer comparison on the objects, you need to use `NSString`'s `isEqualToString:` method:

```
extern NSUInteger someNum;

if([someName isEqualToString:@"abc"]) {
   someNum = 5;
} else if([someName isEqualToString:@"abcd"]) {
   someNum = 6;
}

NSString *newStr = [someString substringFromIndex:someNum];
```

Comment: Works Flawlessly!!! Thanks again Jacob for helping me with my stupidity. Merry Christmas!